# Help a beginner understand differences in candlestick charts

Tags: technical-analysis, yahoo-finance, chart

I have been researching how to read candlestick charts and I'm getting the basics of it, however there is one thing that I just don't understand. I have been watching 1 stock using both Yahoo Finance and Trading View platforms and I've noticed that the candlesticks and stock price is different between these platforms.

For example here is the stock (BPMX) shown with a 5 minute interval on Yahoo Finance.

[image]

Next here is the same stock for the same time period with the same interval only this time the source is Trading View.

[image]

If you look at the last 3 candlesticks you'll notice on Yahoo these sticks have clear bodies, and one of them has wicks coming out of it. However on Trading View these same 3 candlesticks are shown as Doji candles and none of them have wicks.

Furthermore Yahoo shows the stock closing at .1329 and Trading View shows it closing at .1323. Why do these different platforms show different data about the same stock for the same time period? Which is more accurate?

I really prefer working in TradingView because it has way better tools for drawing lines and stuff than Yahoo Finance, but all of the Doji candles make it super hard to see trends and figure out where the support and resistance is.

Comment: The Trading view chart seems to not be capturing all the data in the 5 minute chart, even the time intervals are not even. This could be due to the stock being illiquid or maybe the data capture not been too good. If you go to a longer time frame such as daily it seems to work better. I have even tried the 5min with a different stock and it seems to have better data capture and the time intervals evenly spaced.

Comment: the second chart is just "wrong" in your context.

Comment: Note that candlesticks are only meaningful on day-traded markets; ie instruments which have an open and a close each day.

Comment: Of course, you have the Nison book right ?   https://www.amazon.com/Japanese-Candlestick-Charting-Techniques-Second/dp/0735201811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly because Yahoo Finance and TradingView is using different data sources. In Yahoo Finance, I am pretty sure that for BPMX it is using a data direct from the source, but in tradingview it is clearly indicated that the information is from BATS Trading.
Additionally, yahoo finance data is for some markets are delayed between 10-15 minutes. In tradingview you are able to choose different data sources for the same security if there exists any. When you type the security name, u can choose different sources

For yahoo data source please check this website: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2310.html

and for tradingview check this website:
https://blog.tradingview.com/en/fonte-de-dados-e-bolsas/

And now, another question arises, which is right? Both of them is correct as soon as you use only one of them. Simply focus on tradingview and you are good to go. Because there are a lot of different sources all of them with different prices for the same security.